# Restkit url mapping in POST

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, restkit

I want to POST this URL documents/:ID/resend
and body request

```
{
  "resend":{
    "email": "foo@example.com"
  }
}
```

and response

```
{
   "result":{
      "code": "123",
      "message": "foo"
   }
}
```

I did my request and respond descriptors and this route:

```
RKRoute *documentResendRoute = [RKRoute routeWithClass:[LDocument class]
                                         pathPattern:@"documents/:ID/resend"
                                              method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
```

and when I'm posting the document object

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:self
                                       path:@"documents/:ID/resend" 
                                 parameters:queryParams
                                    success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                        //success code
                                    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                        //failure code
                                    }];
```

Restkit doesn't map the :ID in the URL. It should result something like this "documents/880/resend" but at logs I can see "documents/:ID/resend" and the call fail.

LDocument has the ID property.

What did I miss? or How should I do this?

Thanks, Alejandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `postObject` you shouldn't be specifying the path, if you do this the router won't be used and the parameter not injected. Just set the path to nil.